# Matlab Standalone exe

Tags: executable, matlab-compiler

I built an executable in matlab that converts a .mat file to txt. I am trying to compile it for standalone use on another computer. I added the MCR and it compiles and runs just fine on my computer but on other computers, after installation, the .exe doesn't do anything.

I tried it again with 'Hello world' and I am getting the same result. I call the exe in command prompt but nothing happens.

Comment: I got it to work by compiling it as a terminal exe instead of standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .exe file is probably missing a shared library. If that's the case, it won't run properly until you have the library installed on the other computer. This link also looks like it might help you. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/23369-generating-standalone-executable-file-using-matlab-coder